# syntax error in python shorthand expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 to scrape  a website I have this piece of expression:
`links = ['https://example.com/' + link['href'] for link in school.findAll('a')]`

What I need is to add another condition that if `link` has `href` only than append it with links. Here is the normal code.

```
if link.has_attr('href'):
    //append'
```

I have tried this but found no success

`links = ['https://example.com/' + link['href'] if link.has_attr('href') for link in school.findAll('a')]`

Comment: `['https://example.com/' + link['href'] for link in school.findAll('a') if link.has_attr('href')]`

Comment: @Sraw Done! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two possible way:

**1.**

This will return all link tag if the tag has href attribute.

```
findAll('a',href=True)
```

**2.**

[see list comprehension](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-list-comprehension/)

```
['https://example.com/' + link['href'] for link in school.findAll('a') if link.has_attr('href')]
```

**If you are using bs4, better to use [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method instead `findAll()`**

Answer (score 1):

There is another way which is to only return `a` tags with `href` via css selector:

```
links = ['https://example.com/' + link['href'] for link in school.select('a[href]')]
```